# AttributeError when establishing a foreign key using the to_field option

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to establish a foreign key relationship between two models with a specific field.

Establishing the relationship to the ID fields works correctly, however when I use the `to_field` option I get error:

`AttributeError: type object 'WorldEaseConsignee' has no attribute 'order_number'`

Sample code:

```
class WorldEaseConsignee(models.Model):

    order_number = models.IntegerField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        default=0,
    )


class WorldEaseInvoice(models.Model):      

    order_number_id = models.ForeignKey(
        WorldEaseConsignee,
        to_field=WorldEaseConsignee.order_number,
    )
```

Comment: `order_number` is not a `unique` or `indexed` field. But you could try with this: `to_field='order_number'`

Comment: No luck with adding `unique=True` or `db_index=True` to the Consignee model, nor the invoice model, rather it required `order_number` to be `unique` on consignee and `to_field` to be set as `'order_number'` If you add this as an answer I'll gladly accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs:

> The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object.

As we know PK is unique. Try setting `order_number` as `unique` in `WorldEaseConsignee` model:

```
class WorldEaseConsignee(models.Model):
    order_number = models.IntegerField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=True
    )
```

Also, set `to_field` value as follow:

```
class WorldEaseInvoice(models.Model):
        order_number_id = models.ForeignKey(
            WorldEaseConsignee,
            to_field='order_number',
        )
```